# phpmyadmin 4.5.4.1 & IIs 7.5 loading forever

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

I can log into phpMyAdmin the latest version but if I click on anything it says loading and never loads. I have figured out that I can click on something and then click refresh on the browser and it reloads to what I click on.

Was curious if anyone else was having this issue and if you had a fix for this.

Server info below:

Database server

```
Server: localhost via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.11-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: ******@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Web server

```
Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.6.18
```

phpMyAdmin

```
Version information: 4.5.4.1
```

Comment: In chrome: Control+Shift+I go to the console tab, any errors when you click on things?

Comment: im Using Firefox latest version and also tried it with the microsoft edge the code i got is: **Invalid JSON!JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

Comment: To answer your question then, you're getting a javascript error and it's breaking phpMyAdmin. If you click on that line 1 and read through the JSON object it might give you a clue about what the issue is. My guess is that there's a PHP warning/notice/error that's being thrown inside your JSON response causing it to be invalid. Otherwise, go to the network tab and find the XHR request that's failing and copy the response into http://jsonlint.com/ and it should show you what the issue is. I'd highly recommend setting up virtualbox and a ubuntu server VM to do development against.

Comment: Are you using the English version or a different translation?

Comment: I suggest clearing your browser cache, removing any relevant cookies (they start with "pma"), and trying again.

Comment: Is this a new install or an upgrade? Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: english version is in use. tried deleting all cache and cookies and no there is no real info in the webserver log file. that is saying much more than what the firefox debug console says